# 一つのメールアドレスで異なるゲストアカウントとして投稿できてしまう？

Tags: バグ, アカウント

スタック・オーバーフローではアカウントの登録をせずにゲストとして投稿することができますが、メールアドレスの入力は必須となっています。
(参考までに英語版では投稿前に登録が必須です)

しかし、二つ目のアカウントを登録してしまったユーザーが度々以下のような行動を起こします。

- 質問への編集リクエスト
  質問者本人なら信用度に関わらず編集できるのに、編集リクエストが発生している
  (内容の "追記" であるなら、本人なのか確認する必要がでてくる)
- 回答ではないコメント
  信用度が足らず質問の編集やコメントができないため、回答欄に情報を投稿してしまう
  ("ありがとうございます" や "追加情報です" など)

二つのアカウントが、例えば「会社や学校」と「自宅」との二つのメールアドレスを使用して作成するケースであれば分からなくもないのですが、(モデレーター権限で確認すると) 同一のメールアドレスを使用しているにも関わらず、別アカウントを作成してしまっているケースが多いです。

メールアドレスは本人またはモデレーター以外には非表示な情報ですが、システム的には同じメールアドレスを使用しているなら同一人物とみなすべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: MSE でも投稿済みです。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343278